# How to convert these two date time formats for comparison?

Tags: javascript

One is in the form:

```
2020-09-20T16:26:38.000Z
```

The other is in the form:

```
Sun Sep 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I want to compare the day, month, year only. Thus those two dates should be equal. How can I convert the two dates in javascript so they are equal?

Comment: The first one is a string in ISO date format. The second is the output from the date object toString method. I’d the second one actually a string or is it A date object logging as that string

Comment: Second one is a date object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet assumes dates are strings.
For any of them that is a `Date` object, `var dx=new Date(String)` can be skipped.

```js
var str1="2020-09-20T16:26:38.000Z";
var str2="Sun Sep 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)";

var d1=new Date(str1);
var d2=new Date(str2);

console.log("str1="+str1);
console.log("str2="+str2);
console.log("d1="+d1);
console.log("d2="+d2);
console.log("d1.toDateString()==d2.toDateString() is "+(d1.toDateString()==d2.toDateString()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why `var` instead of `const`?

Comment: @GirkovArpa, Perhaps you are right.
The main reason I don't use `const` and `let` is that dev-tools complains when I copy-paste slightly modified code, sometimes, before I decided what the variable will be.
I know `var` and I use it everywhere, except when developing specific part of code - so I can see what is returned in dev-tools.
It keeps JavaScript loose as it was intended.
I don't know the ("fancy"?) `const` and `let`, yet.
It seems that they restrict it (for reasons I am yet to discover).
So far, I am not convinced they are not plain evil, pointless, and presumptuous.

Answer (score -1):

just new Date

use `Date.getMonth()` or `Date.getFullYear()`

```js
const a=new Date("Sun Sep 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)")
console.log(a)
//2020-09-20T04:00:00.000Z//result a

const b=new Date("2020-09-20T16:26:38.000Z")
console.log(b)
//2020-09-20T16:26:38.000Z// result b

if (a.getMonth()===b.getMonth())console.log("match")
else console.log("not match")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert them both to Date objects (so you get the same format) and then convert them back to strings. Since in both the first 15 chars will now be dates, you can substring them and compare them.

Edit: you don't have to actually convert the second one, as it's already in the correct format, but for the sake of thoroughness, I did

```js
let d1 = new Date('2020-09-20T16:26:38.000Z').toString().substring(0, 15),
    d2 = new Date('Sun Sep 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400').toString().substring(0, 15);

console.log(d1 === d2); //true
```